# Old profile Gmail photo keeps appearing randomly

Tags: gmail, profile

I have changed my Gmail and Google profile pics and when I go into each account they are changed however on my emails an old profile pic is coming up attached to my email account - I can't find it - how do I find and delete?

Comment: Did you try deleting the cache? Make sure to be logged out if you're in Chrome otherwise you're deleting cache forever.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have that picture in WordPress! That happened to me. I forgot I even had a WordPress account because I had it ages ago. The old picture that kept appearing in my emails was the photo uploaded to WordPress. I couldn't change the photo in Google no matter how much I updated it using Google's instructions .Log into WordPress and delete the photo and also turn off Gravatar so that the photo doesn't appear anywhere else. Or if you don't use your WordPress account anymore, do the above first THEN delete your account. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

wow thanks a lot! i spent hours to figure it out but nothing would work. Forgot that I had an account on wordpress -- indeed, avatar linked to that profile was emerging from there 13 years later! Here is what they tell on WordPress. Go to your profile and enable 'Hide my photo and Gravatar profile'...

The avatar you use on WordPress.com comes from Gravatar(opens in a new tab), a universal avatar service (it stands for "Globally Recognized Avatar," get it?).

Your image may also appear on other sites using Gravatar whenever you're logged in with the email

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/155574)